# Finite topological dimension x local compactness

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, dimension-theory, gm.general-mathematics

Of course, the two notions are independent one from the other, but often one of them implies the other under some additional hypotheses. For instance:

A topological vector space is finite dimensional if and only if it is locally compact.

A locally compact topological group with no small subgroups is a finite dimensional Lie group.
(Gleason-Montgomery-Zippin)

A locally arcwise topological group admitting a continuous injective map into a finite dimensional metric space is a finite dimensional Lie group. (Gleason-Palais)

I would like to collect results of this sort in general, and especially concerning topological groups. Does anyone know of any other significant examples?